# Reference for normalization of an algebraic stack?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a standard reference on stacks which discusses (relative) normalization?

[This older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53593/normalization-of-a-stack) seemed to link to someone's notes, but the link is now broken. In any case, it would be nice to have a reference which is a book or a paper.

I've tried the stacks project, Martin Olsson's book on stacks, and Laumon/Moret-Bailly's "Champs Algebriques", and none of them seem to have anything on normalization of stacks (at least not in the index).

Comment: I guess this doesn't classify as a "standard reference", but there is a recent paper of Kenneth Ascher and Dori Bejleri https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06107.pdf that has an appendix about normalizations of algebraic stacks.

Comment: Maybe Section 2.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00488.pdf could be of some help to you.

Comment: Section 5.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04425.pdf has a short discussion of relative normalization of Artin stacks

Answer (score 4):

Quoting

Vistoli, Angelo

Intersection theory on algebraic stacks and on their moduli spaces.

Invent. Math. 97 (1989), no. 3, 613–670.

to be found here http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01388892 :

Definition 1.18 p.623

`Definition. The normalization $F$ of a reduced stack $F$ with a presentation
$R \rightrightarrows U$ is the stack associated with the groupoid $\overline{R} \rightrightarrows \overline{U}$.
The normalization of a general stack is the normalization of its associated
reduced stack.

If $F$ is a stack, the canonical morphism $\overline{F} \to  F$ is representable. If $F$ is of
finite type over a universally japanese ring (see EGA IV, 23.1.1) then $\overline{F} \to  F$
is also finite.'

Here $\overline{R}$ and $\overline{U}$ denote the normalizations of $R$ and $U$, respectively.

Comment: From what I can see this doesn't seem to discuss relative normalization?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but your question wasn't limited to the relative case, was it ?